# How to append every 10 minutes of the range of two different time?

Tags: arrays, swift, date

Lets say I have a start time like this

```
let startTime = "09:00 AM"
```

and an end time like

```
let endTime = "11:00 AM"
```

How can I get every 10 minutes from the range of these to an array.

For example the end product should be

```
array = ["9:00 AM", "9:10 AM", "9:20 AM", "9:30 AM", "9:40 AM", "9:50 AM", "10:00 AM"] //and so on and so on till it reaches "11:00"
```

I've tried comparing two dates but it didn't seem to work and im not sure if I'm on the right track.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)

        let startDate = dateFormatter.date(from: startTime!)!
        let endDate = dateFormatter.date(from: endTime!)!

        var array = [Date]()

        while startDate < endDate {
            startDate.addingTimeInterval(10 * 60.0)
            array.append(startDate)
        }
        print(array)
```

Comment: Show your actual code. You have declared `endTime` twice in your post. Another issue in your code is that `startTime` and `endTime` are not optional and you are forcing to unwrap them

Comment: That was my actual code lol! It was a wording mistake. I've given more details. Thanks

Comment: you are discarding the result of addingTimeInterval you should set `startDate = startDate.addingTimeInterval(10 * 60.0)`. you need also to start your array with startDate as the first element before appending more dates to it

Comment: The new date/time objects are non-mutable

Comment: Make sure your array of date string elements are all wellformed otherwise your forced unwrap will crash your app

Comment: It would be a day of the week but that's not necessarily important I just needed to get the time. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues in your code. First you are discarding the result of addingTimeInterval you should declare startDate as variable and assign the resulting value to it `startDate = startDate.addingTimeInterval(10 * 60.0)`. You need also to start your array with startDate as the first element before appending more dates to it.

```
let startTime = "09:00 AM"
let endTime = "11:00 AM"

let dateF = DateFormatter()
dateF.locale = Locale(identifier:  "en_US_POSIX")
dateF.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
dateF.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"

var startDate = dateF.date(from: startTime)!
let endDate = dateF.date(from: endTime)!

var array = [startDate]

while startDate < endDate {
    startDate = startDate.addingTimeInterval(10 * 60.0)
    array.append(startDate)
}
print(array)
```

This will print

> "[2000-01-01 09:00:00 +0000, 2000-01-01 09:10:00 +0000, 2000-01-01
>   09:20:00 +0000, 2000-01-01 09:30:00 +0000, 2000-01-01 09:40:00 +0000,
>   2000-01-01 09:50:00 +0000, 2000-01-01 10:00:00 +0000, 2000-01-01
>   10:10:00 +0000, 2000-01-01 10:20:00 +0000, 2000-01-01 10:30:00 +0000,
>   2000-01-01 10:40:00 +0000, 2000-01-01 10:50:00 +0000, 2000-01-01
>   11:00:00 +0000]\n"